# Work done on an charged body by magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work

What will be the work done by an uniform magnetic field of magnitude B on an body containing unit positive charge Q and moving with velocity V perpendicular to the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero work is done by the magnetic field.
Write the Lorentz Force Law F = Q(vxB).
As the force is always perpendicular to the direction of velocity, no work is being done by the magnetic forces. The particle would move in a circular arc.